# Return a function on new Model(), then being able to call new on that returned function again?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for the best way to achieve the following use case in JavaScript (if possible at all).

Let's say I want to configure some "Model" entity. Such configuration might be some schema definition or some validation rules. The configuration is kept within the scope of "ModelDef".

```
var ModelDef = new Model({ schema : { name : 'String' }, validation : {} });
```

I then want to be able to initialize instances of a previously defined "ModelDef". This time, I might provide some attributes and their values.

```
var ModelInstance = new ModelDef({ attribute1 : value1, attribute2 : value2 });
```

So far so good. The point is, I want to use the "new" keyword in both cases. While the former ("ModelDef") case can be achieved in a straightforward way, I am wondering whether it is possible to get the second call, which builds on the first one, working, too.

Comment: Since `ModelDef` is a constructor function that is returned from `Model`, it makes no sense to invoke `Model` with `new` (it doesn't change anything though). Why do you "*want*" it, what do you think does it gain you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, since there is no such thing as a `private` or `protected` variable in JavaScript. If you use the keyword `this` other instances will have access. You can, however, use the keyword `var` to create `private` scope that cannot be accessed with the `.`*(dot)* accessor. Additionally, you cannot assign an executed instance of a Constructor to a variable then create a new instance of it, unless the original Constructor returns a Constructor like this nasty example below.

```
function what(c){
  this.a = function(){
    return function(){
      this.b = c;
    }
  }
}
var nasty = new what('test').a();
var testit = new nasty().b;
console.log(testit);
```